# Puede (Ser) Que + subjuntivos

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

- Puede que tenga frío cuando vaya a Kashmir en Invierno.(It may be cold when you go to Kashmir in Winter)
- Puede que tenga frío cuando Iré a Kashmir en Invierno. (It may be cold when I go to Kashmir in Winter)

Pero según la estructura (Cuando + Subjuntivo + Futuro). Cuál es correcto?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to this site. Please visit the tour and help sections to familiarize yourself a little bit bit the style of this site. I formatted your answer, but it may still be a little bit unclear what you might be asking, especially with that vague reference to "Cuando + Subjuntivo + Futuro". I think you should elaborate the question a little bit more. Also, please notice that we favor questions that help learning instead of just doing plain corrections and translations. Thanks and welcome again.

Comment: I don't know how to ask the question in this webside...

Comment: Could you clarify what is the rule you are trying to apply/learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La correcta es la primera frase:

> Puede que tenga frío cuando vaya a Kashmir en invierno.

Aunque el principio de la frase está mal dicha, si lo que quieres decir es: *"It may be cold"* debes decir: *"Puede que esté frio"*.

Pero puede significar tú o yo, te explico. Si quieres referirte a otra persona debes decir:

> Puede que esté frío cuando usted vaya a Kashmir en invierno.

o

> Puede que esté frío cuando tú vayas a Kashmir en invierno.

O si quieres referirte a ti mismo:

> Puede que esté frío cuando yo vaya a Kashmir en invierno.

Comment: For "it is cold", talking about weather, you have to use "hacer". "Puede que **haga** frío".

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is the first one "Cuando vaya a...".The second is quite strange. If you explain better the rule you are trying to apply ((Cuando + Subjuntivo + Futuro) we can explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los usos principales del subjuntivo es para situaciones inseguras.  Por lo tanto, la primera frase es la correcta.  También se usa el subjuntivo para cosas que pueden venir en el futuro.

Compara estas dos frases:

> Cuando sopla el viento, se siente más fuerte el frío.
>
> Cuando vayas a Kashmir en enero, hará frío.

Por otra parte, nota por favor que "Tengo frío" quiere decir que **tú** tienes frío en tu cuerpo (*I am cold*), mientras que "Hace frío" se refiere a la meteorología (*It is cold outside*).