# Puede que nos separen - meaning of "puede"

Tags: definiciones

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Puede que nos separen, pero nunca van a conseguir acabar con nosotros.

This usage of "puede" seems odd to me. Who can? Is it an impersonal expression which means "It is possible" ? I cannot find that meaning in https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=poder. I am familiar with "puede ser", but I have never seen "puede" alone.  Does "puede que nos separen" have the same meaning of "pueden separarnos" ?

Comment: Related post (not a duplicate though, in my opinion): https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19198/9385

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is an impersonal expression which means "It is possible" https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/poder

puede (ser) (= es posible) -> maybe ⧫ it may be so ⧫ perhaps

¡no puede ser! -> that can’t be! ⧫ that’s impossible!

puede (ser) que (+ subjun):

puede (ser) que esté en la biblioteca -> he could or may be in the library ⧫ perhaps he’s in the library

puede (ser) que tenga uno ya -> he may or might have one already

puede (ser) que no venga -> he may or might not come

puede (ser) que tenga razón -> she may or could be right

puede (ser) que sí -> maybe (so)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Naoko -- strong start! // I don't think your link documents this special expression "puede que."  I found another link that refers specifically to this expression though: https://www.spanishdict.com/examples/puede%20que.  Would you like to edit your answer to include it?

Comment: @aparente001 the link includes the expression "puede que", but it includes it as "puede (ser) que", so Ctrl-F'ing "puede que" does not directly work.

Answer (score 1):

El verbo poder no tiene el significado suficiente para ir solo, necesita algún complemento por lo general, de manera explícita o implícita. En el caso que mencionas, hay una oración subordinada subjuntiva, que añade significado a la sentencia.

Por otro lado, el diccionario que mencionas no me gusta demasiado, para inglés está bien pero me fío más de la RAE: https://dle.rae.es/?w=poder

Y para completar la respuesta, no, no tienen el mismo significado. Puede que nos separen tiene un matiz de incertidumbre subjetiva, mientras pueden separarnos no, el hablante no manifiesta juicios.

Comment: Sí, el diccionario Inglés-español no es exhaustivo tanto como es general.